# independence between two functions of random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, independence

If

- $\Theta\sim U[0,2\pi]$
- $R\sim U[0,0.1]$
- $X=R\cdot cos(\Theta)$ and $Y=R\cdot sin(\Theta)$

How can I calculate $cov(X,Y)$ and check the independence between X and Y?

I succeed to find the density function of X and Y in form of; f(R,P) and f(R,Q) [P=sin($\Theta$) and Q=cos($\Theta$)]. But it's seems impossible to caculate the cov(X,Y) without the density function f(X,Y).
There is another way?

Edit:  I'm sorry that I forget to mention that R and $\theta$ are independent. and another correction $R\sim U[0,0.1]$

Update: I found the density functions of P=cos($\theta$) and Q=sin($\theta$).
$f_P(p)=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-p^2}}\mathbb{1}_{[-1;1]}$(p).
$f_Q(q)=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-q^2}}\mathbb{1}_{[-1;1]}$(q).
so that mean the density for X=Rcos($\theta$) and Y=Rsin($\theta$).
$f_{RP}{(r,p)}=\frac{10}{\pi\sqrt{1-p^2}}\mathbb{1}_{[-1;1]}(p)\mathbb{1}_{[0;0.1]}(r)$.
$f_{RQ}{(r,q)}=\frac{10}{\pi\sqrt{1-p^2}}\mathbb{1}_{[-1;1]}(p)\mathbb{1}_{[0;0.1]}(r)$.

but it's not clear to me how I transfer this only to 2 variables X and Y.
at mean $f_{RP}{(r,p)}=f_X(x)$ and $f_{RQ}{(r,q)}=f_Y(y)$

and of course, I need the join density function $f_{XY}{(x,y)}$ for check the cov(x,y). (as @tommik mention above but I don't understand how to get it). Did I do everything right?
and if I get it right, in the end, the results are: X and Y are dependent and uncorrelated?

Comment: What is the relationship between $R$ and $\Theta$?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry that I forget to mention that R and teta are independece

Comment: Edit the question to add this info.

Answer (score 1):

The expectations of $X$ and $Y$ are zero by antisymmetry, and again by antisymmetry the product $(X-\bar X)(Y-\bar Y)$ has a zero expectation (it is positive in two quadrants and negative in the other two).

Comment: Thank you. I guess $ \bar X$ is the expectation of X. So that means that all expectations are equal to zero and the cov(X,Y) is zero also?

Answer (score 0):

It is self evident that the variables $\Theta$ and $R$ are the result of the polar coordinate transformation of $X$ and $Y$.

Thus we can say that the vector $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distribuited on the unit circle:

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\mathbb{1}_{[-1;1]}(x)\mathbb{1}_{[-\sqrt{1-x^2};\sqrt{1-x^2}]}(y)$$

Now you have the joint distribution you were looking for...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So can you assume the joint density function only by know the limit of the cycle? If I change the R range to [0;0.1] the joint probability function be $f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\mathbb{1}_{[-0.1;0.1]}(x)\mathbb{1}_{[-\sqrt{0.01-x^2};\sqrt{0.01-x^2}]}(y)$  am I correct?

Comment: The joint distribution is not uniform on the unit disk. But it is uniform along the circumference of any circle around the origin.